# Keep getting NaNs when carrying out TukeyHSD in R

Tags: r

I have this small data frame that I want to carry out a `TukeyHSD` test on.

```
data.frame':    4 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Species : Factor w/ 4 levels "Anthoxanthum",..: 1 1 1 1 
$ Harvest : Factor w/ 4 levels "b","c","d","e": 1 2 3 4
$ Total   : num  0.2449 0.1248 0.0722 0.1025
```

I perform an analysis of variance with `aov`:

```
anthox1 <- aov(Total ~ Harvest, data=anthox)
anthox.tukey <- TukeyHSD(anthox1, "Harvest", conf.level = 0.95)
```

but when I run the `TukeyHSD` I get this message:

> Warning message:
>
> In qtukey(conf.level, length(means), x$df.residual) : NaNs produced

Can anyone help me to fix the problem and also explain why this is happening. I feel like everything is correctly written (code and data) but for some reason it does not want to work.

Comment: `NaN` means not a number, which is what you get from division by zero.  So you should check if you have a denominator somewhere which should not be zero (but is).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have exactly one observation per group, you get a perfect fit:

```
Total <- c(0.2449, 0.1248, 0.0722, 0.1025)
Harvest <- c("b","c","d","e")
anthox1 <- aov(Total ~ Harvest)

summary.lm(anthox1)
#Call:
#  aov(formula = Total ~ Harvest)
#
#Residuals:
#  ALL 4 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#  
#  Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)   0.2449         NA      NA       NA
#Harvestc     -0.1201         NA      NA       NA
#Harvestd     -0.1727         NA      NA       NA
#Harveste     -0.1424         NA      NA       NA
#
#Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
#F-statistic:   NaN on 3 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

This means you don't have enough residual degrees of freedom for a Tukey test (or for any statistics).

Comment: @Ronald, are you suggesting that 'perfect fit' is the only reason to incur this error or not? I'm running into a situation with the same error while I do a Games Howell test but it seems like not due to a perfect fit as I can still run lots of other tests, like TukeyHSD, with the same data. Just want to make things clear for further debugging of my code.